# Is it possible to make SVN replace keywords when accessing file through WebDAV (www/apache)?

Tags: svn, replace, keyword, webdav

Keywords substitution works file when doing svn update in command line or when using Tortoise SVN client. But when downloading the file through WebDAV (over apache) keywords like $Revision$ $Date$ and $Author are left untouched. Is there a way to change that? I searched Google for any specific setting, but couldn't find anything. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible: just add "?kw=1" to the URL. For example:
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/README?kw=1

This feature available starting from Subversion 1.8:
http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#davkeywordexpansion